# Is it good appraoch for performing CRUD operations on list

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to know about the below approach to perform CRUD operations on a list. It is basically loading the list utilizing model binding features of ASP.NET MVC. Is it advisable to rely on DOM manipulation for insert, delete and update operations.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

If suppose parent.remove() is not implemented correctly, all things get messed up. Is there any template kind of approach to standardize things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as I see Steven Sanderson, I am sure this is good and right approach. Haven't seen a single thing that wasn't makind sense from the guy.

Apparently [no better approach was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974453/mvc-4-more-elegant-way-to-edit-variable-length-list-of-items) yet for ASP.NET MVC. so yes, use that one as if today.

Hope this helps.